# Sum of array items

Tags: arrays, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I am working on React project and I am using **Redux** and **Hooks**. I have problem and wasted 2 days.
I have this array which comes from state:

```js
Array = [
{value: 0, id: 161435}
{value: 1, id: 161435}
{value: 2, id: 161435}
{value: 3, id: 161435}
{value: 4, id: 161435}
,
{value: 1, id: 161434}
{value: 2, id: 161434}
{value: 3, id: 161434}
{value: 4, id: 161434}
{value: 5, id: 161434}
]
```

I want the result like

```js
[{value:10,id:161435},{value:14,id:161434}]
```

I have tried `array.reduce` and it's not work.

Can anyone help me in this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use reduce, do this instead:

```js
const arr = [
  {value: 0, id: 161435},
  {value: 1, id: 161435},
  {value: 2, id: 161435},
  {value: 3, id: 161435},
  {value: 4, id: 161435},
  {value: 1, id: 161434},
  {value: 2, id: 161434},
  {value: 3, id: 161434},
  {value: 4, id: 161434},
  {value: 5, id: 161434},
];

const valueSumById = {};
for (const { value, id } of arr) {
  valueSumById[id] = (valueSumById[id] || 0) + value;
}

const result = Object
  .entries(valueSumById)
  .map(([id, value]) => ({ id, value }));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: i have tried but if have this error :
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{}'

Comment: Oh, you didn't precise it was typescript. Then replace `const valueSumById = {};` by `const valueSumById: Record<string, number> = {};`

Comment: [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gKBjA3gNzgBsBXAUwC4YAGAGhgEsATKgRgDZWAWAZgFYAvrWx5CpSjFb1mbTr0HCcBYuSoAmaS0lz+QkcvFUem2d12LRKiVxPazC-WNWTbHM1z1KnEjYy1veDwsDZ2M-U0DPS0MYG3C7SODvKj5XHSDMAF0AbkxMUEhYbwBlEgBbACEATwBJLQAlMlAEJgAeaAQGMABzejBygCMyBAA+VDwBXIAzEGQACgLoPBhvTRgBGBAp+CQASjwREvLquvRmTPG5o8rapjOmC4AfR5p9gGoVq1yBPMXYBDIEBIRFgaAA8gMAFZNKAiAB0ZDAUE6gKuVlKNzqu3hZTgAAc5nN7vRvJl9igxnNcH4SVZ1rtdrl8uAICAiGQ4UQQN05gCgSDGUA)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const allObj = [
  {value: 0, id: 161435},
  {value: 1, id: 161435},
  {value: 2, id: 161435},
  {value: 3, id: 161435},
  {value: 4, id: 161435},
  {value: 1, id: 161434},
  {value: 2, id: 161434},
  {value: 3, id: 161434},
  {value: 4, id: 161434},
  {value: 5, id: 161434}
]

 const total = []


   allObj.map((obj) => {
     const theIndex = total.findIndex(item => item.id === obj.id);
     if( theIndex === -1){
     total.push(obj)
   } else {
    total[theIndex].value += obj.value;
     }
   });

console.log(total) // [ { value: 10, id: 161435 }, { value: 15, id: 161434 }]
```